# iptables Forwarding and port blocking

Tags: iptables, firewall, port, gateway, dmz

I have created the following Network in Virtual Box:

**Linux Internal PC** with 1 Static IP: ***10.10.10.2***

**Linux Gateway/Firewall** with 2 Static IP's and 1 NAT: ***10.10.10.3*** | ***11.11.11.2*** | **NAT Network Card**

**Linux DMZ Server** with 1 Static IP: ***11.11.11.3***

The targets:
1)Internet on *10.10.10.X* and *11.11.11.X* **via Linux Gateway**. (Only *port 80, 443* allowed to the internet, everything else block)
2)Access to DMZ server from *10.10.10.X* only ***via port 22,80,443*** (everything else blocked from Linux Gateway

The iptables in **Linux Gateway** I have until now is:

```bsh
iptables -F

#Linux Gateway to Internet from 10.10.10.X
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

#Linux Gateway to Internet from 11.11.11.X
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s9 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s9 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Linux Gateway to DMZ
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s9 ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s9 -o enp0s8 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s9 -j MASQUERADE

#Allow only port 80,443 to Internet
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A FORWARD DROP
```

***Edit 1***
1)I have enabled the ip_forward
2)The interfaces are **enp0s8** for *Linux PC*, **enp0s9** for *DMZ*, **enp0s3** for *Internet*

I am not sure if its correct and also I have to add the restriction for ports with destination to DMZ.

Comment: hi, what interface is your internet connection on ?  do you have enabled  ip_forward ?

Comment: Hello, yes I enabled it. The interfaces are enp0s8 for Linux PC, enp0s9 for DMZ, enp0s3 for Internet

Comment: Do you have these three virtual machines running in VirtualBox? How they are connected to the network? Do you have network bridging? Does every virtual machine has itw own dedicated network adapter on the host? Where is this ip tables script executed? On a host or on a virtual machine. On which one? I think you should run separate iptables scripts for each virtual machine. In my opinion, host should not dictate, what is being transferred between virtual machines. I am not even sure it is possible.

Comment: If you linux is not to old, I would suggest migrating to nftables.

Comment: Hi user super, you need at least to ensure your Internet router knows the route to your different subnet using the IP  address of your device in enp0s3, or otherwise add a MASQUERADE on it.   ```iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE ```